# AVPlayer consuming a lot of CPU. Making app stuck randomly

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, avplayer

I am developing a music player app and used AVPlayer for that, I have to play audio from document directory and also stream it directly. But my AVPlayer is consuming a lot of CPU making the app to stuck at random places.

App Flow

1. Initiated an AVPlayer
2. Checked whether the player is in memory or
   not, if yes then replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem with the new audio
   asset.
3. And for stream passed the URL for the asset

Any help I can get.

Any Please let me know what CPU consumption is normal for a music app.

Thanks

```
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];


NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectory returnDocumentDirectoryPath:@"filename.mp3"];
NSURL *soundURL;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
}

if (_player != nil){
    [_player pause];
    [_player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
}


AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:soundURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

_player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
[_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[_player currentItem]];
```

And while changing the track following code is used

```
[_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:soundURL options:nil]]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[_player currentItem]];
    [_player play];
```

And while streaming online

```
 if(!_player)
    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];


resourcePath=@"www.google.com/abc.mp3"//stream URL
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath] options:nil];
NSArray *keys     = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"playable"];

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() {

    if(!playerPlaying){
        [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset]];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Please check the edited post, I updated the code.